# MINIO on localhost?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, storage, minio

I want to set up MinIO as my Django app object storage, and I want to test the functionality of this module on my computer (localhost). I follow the instruction in [django-minio-backend](https://pypi.org/project/django-minio-backend/), but I got the below error.

> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9000): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /django-backend-dev-public?location= (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number
> (_ssl.c:1091)')))

These are lines that I've added to my settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [

...
    'rest_framework',
    'django_minio_backend',
...
]
MINIO_CONSISTENCY_CHECK_ON_START = True
MINIO_ENDPOINT = '127.0.0.1:9000'
MINIO_ACCESS_KEY = 'minioadmin '
MINIO_SECRET_KEY = 'minioadmin '
MINIO_USE_HTTPS = True
MINIO_URL_EXPIRY_HOURS = timedelta(days=1)  # Default is 7 days (longest) if not defined
MINIO_CONSISTENCY_CHECK_ON_START = True
MINIO_PRIVATE_BUCKETS = [
    'django-backend-dev-private',
]
MINIO_PUBLIC_BUCKETS = [
     'django-backend-dev-public',
]
MINIO_POLICY_HOOKS: List[Tuple[str, dict]] = [] here
```

Comment: It looks as if you're trying to make an SSL connection. Have you configured Minio with an SSL certificate? Does it work if you use http instead of https?

Answer (score 0):

As @larks said , it seems that you are making ssl connection to Minio, i.e. https. For this to work you need to install the certificates . More info can be found [here](https://docs.min.io/docs/how-to-secure-access-to-minio-server-with-tls.html)